# 3 Errors in jquery-1.6.1-vsdoc.js when using in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008, vsdoc

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 with KB958502 (.vsdoc hotfix).  This allows us to use IntelliSense to auto-complete JavaScript.

When I use the [jquery-1.6.1-vsdoc](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.1-vsdoc.js), there are three errors:

1. Error updating JScript IntelliSense: jquery-1.6.1-vsdoc.js: 'rootjQuery' is undefined @ 66:2
2. Expected expression @ 1505:16
3. Expected expression @ 2649:15

For #3, Line 2649 is `"checkClone": ,` and simply needs a true or false to be assigned.

For #2, Line 1505 is `"triggered": };` and simply needs to be changed to `"triggered": {} };`

Where I'm getting stuck, though, is #1.  Line 66 is a comment line, so most likely it's referring to Line67 which is `return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );`

Anyone know how to fix this?  Why would MS put something out that has 3 errors right off the bat?  Surely, they test this before putting it out there.

Comment: I think you will not be able to use  jquery-1.6.1-vsdoc because many users have already complaint about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve been searching for an answer to VS2008 intellisense, and I've found the solution...

Add the next at line 67: **rootjQuery = jQuery(document);**

And that make the intellisense of VS2008 works.

By the time I don't know if that is the best solution but it works. :P

Best regards.

Apolo!

Comment: Awesome!  I figured it was something easy.  I don't know why I didn't try that. I would add that you still need to fix those other 2 errors I mentioned in my OP, but that's simple. Great job. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `jquery intellisense support` you can use `jquery 1.4.1` and `jquery 1.4.1.vsdoc`. It is tested in VS2008

Comment: I know I can use that one, but that really isn't the question. There are changes to 1.6 that I wanted in the IntelliSense.

Comment: @Scott: If you really want to use ` jquery-1.6.1-vsdoc.js` then  you should use Visual Studio 2010, its working in VS2010.